# Completing an assignment: Dice Probability

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am working on an assignment for class. I have re-edited my post to show what my desired results are. So far I am stuck on the frequency part. I want to reach these results:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyWpV.png)

Thank you!

import random

```
num = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice? "))
sides = int(input("How many sides does the dice have? "))

def throwDice(num=1, sides=6):
    return [random.randint(1,sides) for i in range(num)]


#-- main ----------------------------------------------------------------------   

numberOfTrials = int(input('How many trials? Enter:'))



# perform simulation, record and print frequencies
frequency= 13*[0]  # same as [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(numberOfTrials):
   t = throwDice()
   frequency[t[0]+t[0]] += 1;

# end for
print()
print("Frequencies:")
print(frequency)


# calculate relative frequencies, probabilities and errors
relativeFrequency = [0, 0]
probability = [0,0]
error = [0,0]
for i in range(2, len(frequency)):
   relativeFrequency.append(frequency[i]/numberOfTrials)
   probability.append(min(i-1,13-i)/36)
   error.append(abs(probability[i]-relativeFrequency[i]))
# end for


#print(relativeFrequency)
#print(probability)
#print(error)
print()


# print results
f1 = "{0:<10}{1:<22}{2:<22}{3:<22}"
f2 = 71*"-"
f3 = "{0:>3}       {1:<22.15f}{2:<22.15f}{3:<.15f}"
print(f1.format("Sum","Relative Frequency","Probability","Error"))
print(f2)
for i in range(2, len(frequency)):
   print(f3.format(i, relativeFrequency[i], probability[i], error[i]))
#end for
print()
```

Comment: If you're going to post an error message, also post the expected behaviour of your program. Sure, we can help you remove the error - but we can't help you fix your code. Not without knowing what your code is supposed to do. Right now, we can only guess what you were trying to do with `frequency[t[0]+t[1]]`.

Comment: I have re-edited my post.

Comment: Those results belong in the body of the question, not on a link outside Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2):

Right.  Look at your routine:

```
def throwDice(rolls=1, dice_sides=6):
    results = 0
    throwDice = 0
    for i in range(0, rolls):
            results = random.randint(1, dice_sides)
    return throwDice
```

...

```
   t = throwDice()
   frequency[t[0]+t[1]] += 1;
```

You make the given quantity of rolls, keeping the last one in `results`.  Then you ignore that one value and return the `0` you initially assigned to the local variable `throwDice` (which, incidentally, locally disables your function definition).  Then you return the 0 to the calling program.

You cannot take the first and second elements of an integer.

How did you accumulate so much code without knowing your function is dysfunctional?  Try testing small blacks before you continue.  In fact, try testing at all: a few minutes with well-placed print statements would point out the problem.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: I fixed then and it now yields results. I have updated the post with the desired results. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

`t` is an int, so `t[0]` has no valid meaning.